# Make cursor paint on canvas in webflow

Tags: animation, cursor, webflow

Need help making my cursor paint in webflow.

I want to create a canvas on my website to allow users to paint when they move the mouse pointer.

I've tried using the interaction feature in webflow but it isn't what i'm looking for

Does anyone know how this can be done?